# 3rd Party JWT Verification for Authentication without the JWT Secret

Tags: security, authentication, jwt

I suppose this is not so much 3rd party as a trusted second party. In our application, we have a private trusted Identity Provider that issues a JWT upon successful authentication to that provider. We are allowed server-to-server communication to perform this authentication, so it's not a 3 legged OAuth flow or anything like that.

Now the token being a JWT we know when it expires but rightfully so we **do not** possess the secret used to sign the JWT so we cannot verify it on our end. This is the only piece of information we have to know if the user is signed in or not. This raises a question:

Since we cannot verify the token's signature we are left just trusting some data that basically anyone with a modicum of skill can set on their own bypassing the authentication flow.  Now before everyone shouts and screams, any kind of user data presentation or any actions that can change a users data etc **MUST** all go to that trusted 2nd party that **DOES** verify the token's signature as it possesses the secret.

The primary flaw I see here is that we would just assume "someone" is signed in assuming a cookie is set. Effectively they would see a "logout" button in their menu. The second they go to any sensitive or actionable section of the application though the token is sent to the trusted second party (over SSL) to retrieve or change information. So a maliciously created token would fail there.

This idea of

> well they would only see a logout button at most

doesn't sit well with me as the application has effectively said "this user is logged in" even if the JWT may not verify and it relies on the fact that the main application currently performs no actions outside of what the second party allows.

I'm curious if there are any well informed techniques that would deal with this issue of:

> implicitly trust the cookie value until the 2nd party, upon an action request, says otherwise.

Here are a few solutions we were thinking of:

- **Send the JWT to the identity provider each request to verify it**

  - Feels like it's defeating the purpose of the JWT to begin with.
  - Adds some extra HTTP overhead per request
- **The first time we see the JWT we verify it with the 2nd Party and, if valid, sign it ourselves**

  - Since we would control the verification request we would know the result can be trusted. Generating our own signature then would prevent always asking the 2nd party for verification.
  - If our app needs to access some of the JWTs payload info we just ensure that our signature verifies first.
  - In the event that our application grows beyond what the 2nd Party allows, this potentially adds a touch of future proofing as a mechanism would be in place to deny a maliciously created JWT.

Obviously the second idea seems more favorable:

- Are there obvious pitfalls we are missing?
- Are there better ways to approach this problem?
- Is this even a concern that should be addressed?

Comment: I am surprised no one has answered this question.  I am in the process of creating a service similar to your trusted 2nd party, and I can already see several mistakes they have made.  I'll take a stab at answering, if it is still an issue for you.

Comment: Always love to hear another take on it.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the obvious pitfalls you already mentioned.

---

The major issue is that they do not issue you a shared secret.  The trusted 2nd party should be issuing subsidiary shared secrets to all of their direct users that will allow you to verify signatures at your portal without having to contact their server to verify JWTs.

We plan on using a JavaScript file that you would include on your web portal that will allow your users to login directly with our servers.  The JWTs would be signed using the shared secret that we have for you.  From here, the JWT would be issued to the user who would submit it to your server in subsequent requests, which you could verify with the same shared secret.

Fixing this issue will fix all of the other issues that you mention, as well as issues of session persistence/expiry, signature revocation, and use of excessive headers/requests.